# Please explain the big effect of a subtle difference in calling syntax when using .then() with a promise

Tags: node.js, promise

I am learning about promises in node.js, and created a simple script to try out different scenarios. When using `.then(..)` to chain promises, I came across a major difference of outcome arising from a subtle difference in syntax, which puzzles me.

My script defines a simple promise function `timerPromise(id, secs)` that returns a promise which fulfils after a timer delay.

```
function timerPromise( id, secs  = 1 ){
    log( `Creating promise ${id}` );
    return new Promise( function( fulfill, reject){

        setTimeout( 
            () => {
                expiredTimersCount++;
                log( `Timer #${id} finished after ${secs} seconds`)
                fulfill( `timerPromise ${id} fulfilled` ) ;
            }
        , secs * 1000);
    });

};
```

To test chaining of promises I used this code, which does not produce the desired result:

```
timerPromise( `#1`, 1 )
    .then( (res)=>{ log( `Timer #1 promise has completed, res=[${res}]`); return "AAA" } )
    .then( timerPromise( `#2`, 3) )
    .then( (res)=>{ log( `Timer 2a chained promise has completed, res=[${res}]`); return "BBB" } )
    .then( (res)=>{ log(`Final result res=[${res}]`)});

log("Timer chain scheduled")
```

In the above case, the last two `.then(..)` steps were run after `timerPromise #1` had fulfilled, but before `timerPromise #2`, despite being after timer #2 in the chain. The console log output was:

```
1: Creating promise #1
2: Creating promise #2
3: Timer chain scheduled
4: Timer ##1 finished after 1 seconds
5: Timer #1 promise has completed, res=[timerPromise #1 fulfilled]
6: Timer 2a chained promise has completed, res=[AAA]
7: Final result res=[BBB]
8: Timer ##2 finished after 3 seconds
```

After a bit of experimentation, I found that this code works as expected:

```
timerPromise( `#1`, 1 )
    .then( (res)=>{ log( res ); log( "Timer #1 promise has completed") } )
    .then( () => timerPromise( `#2`, 3 ) )
    .then( (res)=>{ log( res ); log( `Timer 2a chained promise has completed`) } );

log("Timer chain scheduled")
```

In this case, the console log output is:

```
1: Creating promise #1
2: Timer chain scheduled
3: Timer ##1 finished after 1 seconds
4: Timer #1 promise has completed, res=[timerPromise #1 fulfilled]
5: Creating promise #2
6: Timer ##2 finished after 3 seconds
7: Timer #2 promise has completed!, res=[timerPromise #2 fulfilled]
8: Final result res=[BBB]
```

My question is, why does the syntactic difference between the first and second examples result in an actual difference in chaining `.then()`s? It seems to be something to do with the point at which the second promise is created - at step 2 in the first case, and at step 5 in the second.

I can understand that in the first case Timer 2 starts before Timer 1 has finished, but even so the function returns a promise, so shouldn't it replace the earlier Timer 1 in the chain, so that the subsequent steps in the chain should wait for the Timer 2 promise to be fulfilled?

Comment: to make your original `.then` chain work you'd have to modify `timerPromise` to be a function that _returns a function_ that when (eventually) invoked returns that new Promise.

Comment: Thanks @Alnitak! Yes, I think I am getting the hang of the way that Promises work, although it gets dead confusing at times!

Comment: Hmmmm.. A down vote seems a bit harsh. I thought I had put in quite a bit of effort and research, and explained the issue very clearly. Yet I was still genuinely puzzled.

Comment: @Alnitak - actually, I have created two new functions `parallelTimer(id, secs)` which creates a new timerPromise then returns a function that returns the new promise, and `serialTimer(id, secs)` which returns a function that creates and returns a new timerPromise. They both work a treat when used in the `.then(..)` chain! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with promises themselves.

`.then` expects to be passed a function that can be called when the promise resolves. When you do `` .then(timerPromise( `#2`, 3)) `` your calling `timerPromise` *first* and pass its return value to `.then`, which is a promise, **not** a function.

In JavaScript, whenever you do `foo(bar())`, `bar` is called first and its return value is passed to `foo`. That might or might not work depending on what `foo` expects to be passed.

Example:

```js
function foo(func) { console.log(func()); }

function bar() { return 42; }
function barFn() { return function() { return 42; }}

foo(barFn());     // works as expected because barFn returns a function
foo(() => bar()); // works a expected because I pass a function calling bar
foo(bar());       // fails because bar returns a number
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, @FelixKing. So, as I understand it, even though `.then` expects a function, it does not complain if you give it a Promise instead? And, furthermore, it simply ignores the Promise altogether, carrying on with subsequent `.then()`s?

Comment: @JohnRC - Javascript the language does not do type checking.  You can pass anything to anything and it will happily let you shoot yourself in the foot.  If that bothers you, you can use TypeScript which implements type checking.  So, when you pass the wrong thing to `.then()`, it just ignores it.  It was a design decision in the promise implementation/specification for whether to dynamically detect that wrong thing being passed and reject the promise with an error which might be more noticeable, but apparently they decided not to do that.  So, always pass a function reference to `.then()`.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 = Yes I did understand that js does not do type checking, and it is up to the implementer of a function to decide on what parameter type(s) to check for and what, if any, action to take when there is a parameter that does not meet expectations. I am very happy with that. My problem was just the significant consequences of what is a bug in my code (i.e. passing a promise not a function), which I did not understand because I am not so fluent (yet) in js and not so familiar (yet) with promises. Everyone on SO has been helpful so I am improving!

Comment: @JohnRC - Yeah, I personally wish that the promise specification would have made that an error rather than just ignore it silently because it is an indication of a programming error.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Or that the promise is accepted as being a valid step in the chain, so that, for example, the promise could have been created a while back, you just want to be sure that it has resolved before your chain continues. Nevertheless, I really like the lightweight nature of js where there is little run-time overhead of checking stuff - much better than the machine-killing overheads of other languages ;)

Comment: @JohnRC - Well, languages like C/C++ and TypeScript are doing type checking at compile time, not run time.  So, they aren't adding runtime overhead.  You can make a promise chain "wait" or "verify" that a promise has been resolved before continuing the chain by just returning that promise from a `.then()` handler.  There's already a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

A `.then` accepts a *callback*. If you pass a Promise into `.then`, it won't work - it'll resolve immediately. That is:

```
someProm.then(someOtherPromise)
```

doesn't make sense. You instead want:

```
someProm.then(fnThatReturnsSomeOtherPromise)
```

If you *invoke* the function that returns the Promise immediately, you'll get a Promise in return. `.then( timerPromise( '#2', 3) )` will result in `.then` being passed a Promise.

Change it to `.then( () => timerPromise( '#2', 3) )`.

```js
let expiredTimersCount = 0;
const log = console.log;
function timerPromise( id, secs  = 1 ){
    log( `Creating promise ${id}` );
    return new Promise( function( fulfill, reject){

        setTimeout( 
            () => {
                expiredTimersCount++;
                log( `Timer #${id} finished after ${secs} seconds`)
                fulfill( `timerPromise ${id} fulfilled` ) ;
            }
        , secs * 1000);
    });

};
timerPromise( `#1`, 1 )
    .then( (res)=>{ log( `Timer #1 promise has completed, res=[${res}]`); return "AAA" } )
    .then( () => timerPromise( `#2`, 3) )
    .then( (res)=>{ log( `Timer 2a chained promise has completed, res=[${res}]`); return "BBB" } )
    .then( (res)=>{ log(`Final result res=[${res}]`)});

log("Timer chain scheduled")
```

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance. Now I'm puzzled again: if `someProm.then( someOtherPromise )` doesn't make sense, why doesn't `.then()` throw an exception?

Comment: Because the specification doesn't say to throw an error, so no error is thrown. It doesn't make any sense, but it's not completely forbidden. (Consider using TypeScript to turn these sorts of typos into compile-time errors)

Comment: Ah yes, in fact the MDN documentation states specifically in a note that no error is thrown if then() is given a non-function.